# Python remove brackets and quotes from list item

Tags: python, list

I am using Python to return a list item by its index like this:

```
selectedtext = list_of_lists[44]
print("Selected Text Is")
print(selectedtext)
```

And it is returning this:

```
['My Results']
```

How can I remove the brackets and quotes from the result?

Comment: Can the inner lists contain several strings? If so, how would you want those to be displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like index 44 of `list_of_lists` is a list itself so you will need to get the first item in that list. You could do this:

```
selectedtext = list_of_lists[44]
print("Selected Text Is")
print(selectedtext[0])
```

Or:

```
selectedtext = list_of_lists[44][0]
print("Selected Text Is")
print(selectedtext)
```

Comment: Thank you, that explained it perfectly.  Lists within lists have been my problem all along!

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want to print the *first item* of your nested list only. Use indexing:

```
print(selectedtext[0])
```

You were printing a list, and lists, like other containers, include their contents with the [`repr()` output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) for each; printing lists is meant for debugging mostly, not for end-user presentations.

If your list can contain multiple items, and you still want these items to be separated by comments, use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to produce a new string built from the list contents:

```
print(', '.join(selectedtext))
```